# On Cardinals in Boolean-valued models

Tags: logic, set-theory

Question on Boolean-valued models. Does the following always hold (and if so why?):

Claim: For any $x \in \mathbf{V}^{\mathbb{B}}$ we have $\mathbf{V}^{\mathbb{B}} \models  \widehat{\mid  x \mid}= \vert \widehat{x} \mid  $ ? (In the first case "the hat" is over "$\mid x \mid$" whereas in the second case "the hat" is only over "x"). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen  Could you have a look at this question?

Comment: What if $\Bbb B$ is the completion of $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\omega_1)$ and $x=\check\omega_1$?

Comment: (Or rather, to add to my previous comment, it's not entirely clear what you mean by $\widehat{|x|}$ vs. $|\widehat{x}|$ here. Are both of these "the names for something" or is one of the name "the cardinality of the name in $V$" or what?)

Comment: @Asaf I guess $|\hat{x}|$ means the cardinaltiy of $\check{x}$ computed over $V^\mathbb{B}$, and $\widehat{|x|}$ means the check name for the cardinality of $x$ computed over $V$. It seems like you already made such a guess, and it is a good idea to wait the OP's clarification.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, I mean the cardinality of $\check{x}$ (within the Boolean-valued model) v.s. the check name of for the cardinality  of x (within V). Would my claim hold at least for Boolean valued models where the underlying Boolean algebra satisfies c.c.c?

Comment: @HanulJeon Yes, This is exactly what I mean!!

Comment: Then Asaf's example is a counterexample of your claim.